# Edit closed question or ask a new one?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

Yesterday there was a [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/is-it-confusing-to-have-a-user-driven-site-named-after-its-audience-instead-of-i) heavily discussed on the context of naming a Q'n'A site according to the title of the job, or the activity of the work. It was rightfully closed as "too localized" since it mentioned only one domain.

Still I think the question, or an unlocalized version of it, is well suited on UX.SE. It concernes Labeling in the context of Information Architecture - and I would love to have the ability to answer that question.

Now, do I edit the question at hand, unlocalizing it and hoping it to reopen, or ask a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's leave the current closed question alone since it was so controversial. If you want to re-ask a similar question (one that passes the various tests we have in place for good questions), you can of course go ahead!

Comment: A new one it is then. Thanx Rahul!